# I need help writing a test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

I have written the below trigger and helper class. I am a newbie and pieced the trigger and class together with help from various forms. It works fine in sandbox but I have no idea how to write the test class so I can deploy to production. I have 4 almost identical  triggers (except for group names) and 1 helper class

Trigger

```
trigger Addtogroup1 on Contact (after insert, after update) {

      List<GroupMember> GMlist = new List<GroupMember>();
       Set<String> contactEmails = new Set<String>();
       for(Contact con : Trigger.New) {
          //create a set with the contact email addresses
          contactEmails.add(con.email);
       }

       //query for the related users and put them in a map,
       //where the key is the email and the value is the user
       Map<String, User> emailUserMap = new Map<String, User> ();
       for(User aUser : [select id, email from User where email in : contactEmails]){
          emailUserMap.put(aUser.email, aUser);
       }
           system.debug(emailUserMap);
           List<Id> userIdList = new List<Id>();
      for(Contact con : Trigger.New) {
        if(con.Public_Group_Service_Partner_Content1__c == TRUE) {    

             userIdList.add(emailUserMap.get(con.email).id);

          }
      }  

      //dymanically get the get group id.
      Group theGroup = [select id from Group where Name = 'Service Partner Content'];
      if(null != theGroup){
          //call the contact trigger helper if the group exists. 
          //This method adds the user to the group
          ContactTriggerHelper.addUsersToGroup(theGroup.id,userIdList );
      }
  }
```

Helper Class

```
public class ContactTriggerHelper{

  //future call to do the group adding.  the future call will spawn a new thread.
  @future
  public static void addUsersToGroup(String groupId, List<Id> userIds){
      List<GroupMember> GMlist = new List<GroupMember>();
      for(ID userId: userIds){
          GroupMember gm = new GroupMember();
          gm.GroupId = groupId;
          gm.UserOrGroupId = userId;
          gmList.add(GM);
      }


      if(gmList.size() > 0){
          insert gmList;
      }
  }

}
```

I tried using this test class

```
@isTest

private class AddtoGroupTest
{
    static void createGroup(Boolean isGroup)
    {

        // Insert contact with your required field.

        Contact cnt = new Contact();
        cnt.LastName = 'Test contact';
        cnt.Email = 'test@test.com';
        cnt.Public_Group_Technology_Partner_Content__c = true;
        insert cnt;

        // Insert user

        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='test@test.com',
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com');
        insert u;

        // Insert Group
        if(isGroup == true)
        {
            Group grp = new Group();
            grp.Name = 'Technology Partner Content';
            grp.DeveloperName = 'Technology Partner Content';
            insert grp;
        }
    }



    static testMethod void insertWithGroup()
    {
        createGroup(true);
    }

    static testMethod void insertWithoutGroup()
    {
        createGroup(false);
    }
}
```

But I got this error

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Addtogroup4: execution of
>   AfterInsert
>
> caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null
>   object
>
> Trigger.Addtogroup4: line 21, column 1: []

Again I am a newbie and have no idea how to correct this or if I am on the right path with the test class so if anyone could show me what it should look like I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

These are few notes for writing code/tests that might help you:

- Use variable names so it is clear what they contain. It is not relevant to know if it is a map or set or a list.
- Use name convention for triggers/classes/etc. as already defined by best practices (check online for more resources).
- Before accessing an object property (ie user.id), check the object is not null.
- When testing future methods, call it or create data that calls it in Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest(), and after that assert expected behaviour.
- I noticed that you are calling methods, but not asserting (verifying) expected results. Tests must use asserts. Also aim for 100% coverage not the minimum coverage required. 
  When testing, I follow the next approach:

a) setup data,

b) act (call the methods) and

c) assert that output is as expected.

Just calling methods to have the minimal code coverage is not testing.

- When wanting to test using a certain profile, *never* (sorry to use this word but I must) create a user since it will fail if there is an issue with licensing. Use "runAs()". Set the user object and then use "System.runAs(yourUser){}" -> this statement will create the user to be utilized in a test method.
  http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/using-system-runas-in-test-methods
- Since you are starting with Apex, it is best to start with the best practices when coding. One of them is to use Trigger framework so it is easy to plugin your custom logic inside a trigger. Examples of trigger frameworks are: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices 
  http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/trigger-pattern-for-tidy-streamlined-bulkified-triggers

This is my attempt to write the above trigger:

```
trigger ContactAddUserToGroup on Contact (after insert, after update) {
       List<GroupMember> groupMembers = new List<GroupMember>();
       Set<String> contactEmails = new Set<String>();
       Map<String, User> usersByEmail = new Map<String, User>();
       List<Id> userIds = new List<Id>();

       for (Contact c : Trigger.New) {
          contactEmails.add(c.email);
       }

       for (User u : [SELECT id, email FROM User WHERE email IN :contactEmails]){
          usersByEmail.put(u.email, u);
       }

      for (Contact c : Trigger.New) {
        if (c.Public_Group_Service_Partner_Content1__c == true && 
            usersByEmail.containsKey(c.email)
          ) { 
             userIds.add(usersByEmail.get(c.email).id);
          }
      }  

      Group group = [SELECT id FROM Group WHERE Name = 'Service Partner Content'];
      if (group != null) {
          ContactTriggerHelper.addUsersToGroup(group.id, userIds);
      }
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This error has occured because in the line 
userIdList.add(emailUserMap.get(con.email).id);
there is no value in the map emailUserMap corresponding to the contact email key.

Also there are some changes to be made in the  code.
1) Before adding a specific value to set check if the value is null. In this case , before adding contact email to contactEmails set check if the field has value in it and then add it
2) Before querying based on a set, check if the set has values in it and then proceed. in this case the code can be written as

if(contactEmails.size()>0)
List  userDetails=[select id, email from User where email in : contactEmails];

if(userDetails.size()>0){
 Map emailUserMap = new Map ();
       for(User aUser :userDetails ){
          emailUserMap.put(aUser.email, aUser);
       }
}

In the test class, insert the user first and then insert the contact with the user's email in the contact email field

Answer (score 0):

The error mentions "AddtoGroup4" but your posted code only mentions AddtoGroup1.  Can you post AddtoGroup4 as well?
Also, in your test class, try adding an account first, then your contact.